# Swagger document ordered differently in different environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, .net-6.0

I have set up swagger actions order by `RelativePath` and `HttpMethod`

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
   c.OrderActionsBy(api => $"{api.RelativePath}_{api.HttpMethod}");
}
```

which sort correctly on my local machine:

[image]

but different in staging, seems it's ordered descending:

[image]

why??

Environment:

- .NET SDK `6.0.400`
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore `6.4.0`
- Local runs on Apple M1, staging deployed on AWS Fargate using docker image `dotnet/runtime-deps:6.0-alpine`